AWS SDK - Readable Stream Error while using CognitoIdentityProvider or any aws-sdk
When Trying to Access the Cognito Provider to Login in React Native, error as Reference Error - Readable Stream Not Found
Version Details
"react-native": "0.69.3",
"@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs": "^3.614.0",
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';

const client = new AWS.CognitoIdentityProvider({ region: EnvConfig.REGION })

const getTokens = async ({username, password}) => {
    try {
      setisLoading(true);
      const {AuthenticationResult} = await client.initiateAuth({
        ClientId: EnvConfig.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters: {
          USERNAME: username,
          PASSWORD: password,
        },
      });
      console.log({
        access_token: AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
        id_token: AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
        refresh_token: AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
      });
      setisLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      setisLoading(false);

      ToastMessage(error.message);
    }
  };

I thought it might be becuase of the Some Dependancy Issue in my Project. So I created a new react native Project. Below is the Package.json file.
package.json
    "@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs": "^3.614.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.614.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "web-streams-polyfill": "^3.3.3"

Tried to Implement the Cognito Login and was facing the Same Issue
[ReferenceError: Property 'ReadableStream' doesn't exist]
With the reference of this I Added
Tried with "web-streams-polyfill": "^4.0.0" (latest version)

import {ReadableStream} from 'web-streams-polyfill'
globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;


UPDATE  -
The Latest Version of web-streams-polyfill can be used as mentioned here
Then got an error as [TypeError: null is not a function]
Tried with "web-streams-polyfill": "^3.3.3"

import ReadableStream from 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill';
globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;


Then got an error as [TypeError: right operand of 'instanceof' is not callable]
Stuck in this and im not able to find solution.
